# Add new column containing an Array of column names sorted by the row-wise values pyspark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

I am pretty new to Pyspark. I found somebody already ask this question long time ago [Add new column containing an Array of column names sorted by the row-wise values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073019/add-new-column-containing-an-array-of-column-names-sorted-by-the-row-wise-values)

Given a dataFrame with a few columns, I'm trying to create a new column containing an array of these columns' names sorted by decreasing order, based on the row-wise values of these columns.

```
| a | b | c | newcol|
|---|---|---|-------|
| 1 | 4 | 3 |[b,c,a]|
| 4 | 1 | 3 |[a,c,b]|
---------------------
```

This is their solution for Scala

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1,4,3), (4,1,3))).toDF("a", "b", "c")

val names=df.schema.fieldNames
val sortNames = udf((v: Seq[Int]) => {v.zip(names).sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)})
df.withColumn("newcol", sortNames(array(names.map(col): _*))).show
```

I having trouble translating this code to Python

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 3), (4, 1, 3)], "a: int, b: int, c: int")
colNames = df.columns

@udf
def orderByColValue(colValues: list):
    return [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(colValues, colNames), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)]

df.withColumn("ordered_cols", orderByColValue(array(colNames))).show(truncate=False)

+---+---+---+------------+
|a  |b  |c  |ordered_cols|
+---+---+---+------------+
|1  |4  |3  |[b, c, a]   |
|4  |1  |3  |[a, c, b]   |
+---+---+---+------------+
```